# Postlogin hook kind of functionality using servlets, filters

Tags: java, servlets, web-applications, servlet-filters

I have a requirement in my webApp, where I need to generate internal password for the users who log in with valid credentials. That is this internal password generation functionality will take place only once in the user's session lifetime.I need to put this internal password into user's session.
Similar functionality can be achieved in liferay with postlogin hook, but I don't know how to achieve the same thing with only Servlets and filters.
NOTE: I am using JAAS for user authentication.

I did something like: in servlet-filter, I check for the internal password in the session, if it does not exist then generating. But after user logs in and there are multiple requests at the same to the server then unnecessarily multiple passwords will be created. This password generation is a costly affair.

Can someone suggests me something else?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know, how JAAS Authentication works, im just referring to that part:

> I need to put this internal password into user's session...

If you want to store anything to a user's session for later processing, you could do this in your serlvets code

```
protected final void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
   HttpSession session = request.getSession(true); //this returns an existing session, or creates new one
   session.setAttribute(key,value);
... 
}
```

Those stored objects are as long available as the session lives.

> I did something like: in servlet-filter, I check for the internal password in the session, if it does not exist then generating. But after user logs in and there are multiple requests at the same to the server then unnecessarily multiple passwords will be created. This password generation is a costly affair.

If the internal password generation is costly, you shouldnt create them in the servlet filtering classes, as those filters apply on any request made by a client to server. Move the relevant code of pw generation to e.g. servlet, which performs the actual validation of user credentials. If credentials are fine, create the password once and store it in the session object, mentioned above.

**Update:**
So assuming you have some kind of html form

```
<form method="post" action="AuthServlet">
  <input type="text" name="username">
  <input type="password" name="pwd">
  <input type="submit" value="login">
</form>
```

AuthServlet (Note: this servlet is called only once, when user tries to log in):
Further assumption, you need some kind of server side hook functionality, as you said, you want to generate internal passwords

```
@WebServlet("/AuthServlet")
public class AuthServlet 
    extends HttpServlet {
//  .. lines omitted ..

   @Override
   protected final void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
           HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException {

      // ... lines omitted 

      // perform authentication with JAAS
      try {
         LoginContext loginContext = new LoginContext("SomeName", handler);
         // starts the actual login
         loginContext.login();

         //at this point, user is authenticated..normally you would forward him to e.g. a jsp, welcoming the user
         //request.getRequestDispatcher("anyJsp.jsp").forward(request, response);

         //but you can also forward to another serlvet and perform business logic or else
         request.getRequestDispatcher("/ServletName").forward(request, response); 

      } catch (LoginException e) {
         //do sth., if auth fails
      }
 }
```

In the servlet denoted with `ServletName`, you can perform within `doPost()` your password generation, and attach this pwd to user's session.
If you have some kind of user model, and user have e.g. roles. You can query the role, and forward to servlet depending on the role.
Is this more helpful ?

Comment: That is fine to add the internal password generation logic while authenticating the user. So, I need to add this logic in JAAS authentication module. But, my question was specific to pure servlets. But my question was: Is there any way to get a call to a servlet post login only once like any configuration in web.xml.

Comment: Please don't show how to set the values into session. I think from my question it is clear that I have worked with Servlets and have basic knowledge about the server side technologies.
But thanks for the answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer, i have to admit, that maybe i didnt understand you properly, see my assumptions above

Comment: This seems to be the proper one. Thanks a lot friend.